# what is missing in my regex to match?

Tags: java, regex

I have this java regex \ matcher:

```
private static final Pattern RC_COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^RC,([\\d]+),(.*)$");
```

and this code:

```
   private Iterable<ClientCommand> tryToDeserializeNonProtocolBufferContent(byte[] content) {
        String body = "RC,200,OK\nBridgeToRes,UPDATEPROFILE,916,0";
        Matcher rcCommandMatcher = RC_COMMAND_PATTERN.matcher(body);
        if (!rcCommandMatcher.find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
...    
    }
```

but I see the execution reaches `rcCommandMatcher.find() == false`

why is my matcher failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dot can't match by default the newline character.

To do that you need to use the s modifier (or the DOTALL flag), example:

```
private static final Pattern RC_COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^RC,([\\d]+),(?s)(.*)$");
```

or

```
private static final Pattern RC_COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^RC,([\\d]+),(.*)$", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Your pattern can be written like that:

```
private static final Pattern RC_COMMAND_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\ARC,(\\d+),(.*)\\z", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

*(The brackets around `\d` are useless since `\d` is already a character class. The use of `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` is less ambigous because the meaning of `\A` and `\z` don't change whatever the mode (mulitiline or not))*

Comment: what does `(.*)` means without this flag?

Comment: capture any character except line breaks, zero or more times.

Comment: @EladBenda: The `.` means any character except the newline character `\n`

Comment: `Pattern.DOTALL`  didn't help. still not a match

Comment: @EladBenda: The problem is not the pattern in this case, it is probably somewhere else in your code. You can see a working demo here: http://fiddle.re/axh1y6 (click the Java button)

Comment: But the mismatch is very local. The pattern, the body. This is all that matters

Comment: I think it's the debugger evaluation that cased the code evaluation run match second time and return "false"

Comment: @EladBenda: Possible, the `find()` method is not appropriate here since you are trying to match all the string, It's better to use the `matches()` method *(in this case, you can remove anchors)* or `lookingAt()` to only check the begining *(you can remove `(.*)$` in this case. except if you want to capture something)*